# linq to sql -error when insert on 2 entites parent child relationship

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have order & order details entities with OrderID as foreign key in order details table.
OrderID is the identity column for Order and is set to autogenerate.

When I do an insert as follows (hardcoded values for simplicity):

```
LINQ1DataContext db = new LINQ1DataContext();

Order order = new Order();
order.OrdersCustomerID = 1;
order.OrdersDate = time;
db.Orders.InsertOnSubmit(order);

OrdersDetail oDetail = new OrdersDetail();
oDetail.OrdersDetailID = order.OrdersID;
oDetail.OrdersDetailProdID = 1;
oDetail.OrdersDetailQty = 6;
oDetail.OrdersDetailUnitPrice = 2.58m;
db.OrdersDetail.InsertOnSubmit(oDetail); 

db.SubmitChanges();
```

This results in a 'conflict with the FOREIGN KEY constraint' error.
I found this was because an orderID is not being generated at InsertOnSubmit(order). When the SubmitChanges() is then run, OrdersDetailID doesnt match OrdersID and get the error. OrderID will only get generated following a 'submitchanges()'.

If put in an extra db.SubmitChanges(); after the db.Orders.InsertOnSubmit(order), orderid gets autogenerated as I expect and orderDetails then inserts fine.

My question is, is it normal to have to put in a submitChanges after every insertOnSubmit when inserting into 2 tables (parent-child) like this?

I thought the idea of insertOnSubmit was I could do a couple of inserts on different tables and LINQ to SQL would look after the all the details following a SubmitChanges.

thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Adding

```
order.OrdersDetail.Add(oDetail);
```

before

```
db.OrdersDetail.InsertOnSubmit(oDetail);
```

seemed to work and only needed one db.SubmitChanges(). Maybe that's the way to do this type of thing..

Answer (score 0):

```
LINQ1DataContext db = new LINQ1DataContext();

Order order = new Order();
order.OrdersCustomerID = 1;
order.OrdersDate = time;
db.Orders.InsertOnSubmit(order);

> db.SubmitChanges();

OrdersDetail oDetail = new OrdersDetail();
oDetail.OrdersDetailID = order.OrdersID;
oDetail.OrdersDetailProdID = 1;
oDetail.OrdersDetailQty = 6;
oDetail.OrdersDetailUnitPrice = 2.58m;
db.OrdersDetail.InsertOnSubmit(oDetail); 

db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Doing a submitchanges in the middle is the wrong message.  Instead he found the right solution himself, which was to let the framework hook up the foreign keys himself.  If you simply add the detail record to the parent record through the connection property, like order.OrdersDetails.Add(oDetail) (instead of InsertOnSubmit(oDetail)) and don't set the foreign key at all in the child then it will update automatically with only one submit.