# Linq to SQL parent-child relation direction

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have a parent-child relation among two tables named: Relation and Resource, so that Relation.RESOURCE_ID == Resource.ID

If I write my association into the dbml file, so that Relation --> Resource on RESOURCE_ID = ID then I am unable to add a Resource to a Relation entity. The cardinality of association is one to one.

```
tbl_res_Resource resoure = new tbl_res_Resource()
{
    //ID is auto calculated
    RESOURCE_KEY = "some key",
    RESOURCE_TYPE = 20,
};

tbl_res_Relation relation = new tbl_res_Relation()
{
    ENTITY_ID = 10,
    ENTITY_TYPE_ID = 10,
    //ID is auto calculated
    //RESOURCE_ID should be inferred
};


relation.Resource = resoure;

context.tbl_res_Relations.InsertOnSubmit(relation);
context.SubmitChanges();
```

Submit changes will throw

> System.Data.Linq.ForeignKeyReferenceAlreadyHasValueExceptio with the message 'Invalid operation due to the current state of the object'.

But if I go to the model (dbml) and reverse the association ( so Resource --> Relation on ID == RESOURCE_ID) then everything work fine.. without changing a line of code.

Keep in mind that all the association are defined only at dbml level, there is no foreign key into database.

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I am missing here?

Nothing, that is correct. It doesn't matter that the cardinality is one-to-one. An association in LINQ2SQL is an abstraction in the application layer that is the equivalent of defining a foreign key in the database layer. And LINQ2SQL expects you to follow the constraints of that association just the same as you would have to follow the constraints of an equivalent foreign key in the database layer.

> what i don't understand is why reversing the 1-1 association (in teh dbml model) will break the association. It's a one to one, it does not have a preferred direction nor constraints at DB level.

Again this has nothing to do with cardinality (one-to-one) and associations always have a direction (parent to child(ren)) depending on how you set them up. If you look in the Properties window of the association, you'll see it says which object is the Parent and which is the Child.

In your code you're setting the `relation.Resource` field to a `resource` object, ergo saying that the `resource` is the parent and `relation` is the child:

```
relation.Resource = resoure;
```

The above is the equivalent of in the database layer making `relation` the child table with a foreign key defined on the `Resource` field relating back to the parent `resource` table.

If your association is defined such that `relation` is the parent, then your above code fails to the constraint because you have a `resource` child object that you're not assigning a parent to. You would need something like the following to adhere to the constraint:

```
resource.Relation = relation;
```

Comment: Yes that is clear to me, what i don't understand is why reversing the 1-1 association (in teh dbml model) will break  the association. It's a one to one, it does not have a preferred direction nor constraints at DB level. So if it work in one specific direction (child to parent) why doesn't work in the opposite (when modelled right)?  Because it's very difficult to understand that the child is modelled as parent, just to make the assoiation work as intended.

Comment: @Skary Please see my updated answer. I think the part you're getting tripped up on is not realizing associations **always** have a direction, and it matters (as that direction defines the direction of the relational constraint in the application layer).

Comment: So basically i need to assign a parent to a child and never otherwise? If this is how Linq To SQL work then I understand what confuse me. I expect i can also assign a child to a parent and is the same (i mean i try to do so changing the dbml twice, at least in one case should be correct). Because here is see people proceede exaclty as i would, assigning a detail (child) to and order (a parent) and not viceversa : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356988/linq-to-sql-error-when-insert-on-2-entites-parent-child-relationship  Why can't i do this?

Comment: Sorry for the double comment but i would like to be clear, i know there is a direction in DBML, and i have just tried again switching it. But seems that in any case i have to assign parent to a child, but in the linked example (and from what i remeber) there should be the possibility to assign a child to a parent. I don't care which direction i have to choose in DBML (there is not a preferred one "logically"), i found more "correct" and readable to assgin child to parent and not viceversa (this is my goal).

Comment: @Skary Yes, it may seem counter-intuitive syntactically, but your instance of your child object has a property for the parent (just like in the database a child table would have a column for the foreign key field that relates to the parent table). You need to set this property on the child object (just like in the database you would be required to fill in that foreign key column). So yes, when you have an association defined between two objects, if you create an instance of the child object, the association has a constraint that enforces you to set the parent property of that child object.